# how to deselect some part of data of object to not appear in response

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, mern

In my my mern project when the user do login in the response my server sends him the response of with hash password and reset password token is there any way to fix it

[image]

Here is my user model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const validator = require("validator");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const crypto = require("crypto")

const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "please Ente the your name"],
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Please Enter the email"],
    unique: [true],
    validate: [validator.isEmail, "Please Enter a valid email"],
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: [8, "Passwaord must be more that 8 characters"],
    select: false,
  },
  avatar: {
    public_id: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    url: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  role: {
    type: String,
    default: "user",
  },
  resetPasswordToken: String,
  resetPasswordExpire: Date,

  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});

userSchema.pre("save", async function (next) {
  if (!this.isModified("password")) {
    next();
  }

  this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 10);
});

userSchema.methods.comparePassword = async function (password) {
  return await bcrypt.compare(password, this.password);
};

userSchema.methods.getJWTToken = function () {
  return jwt.sign({ id: this._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
    expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRE,
  });
};

// compare password

// userSchema.methods.comparePassword = async function(enterPass){
//     return await bcyrypt.compare(enterPass,this.password)
// }

// Reset Password

userSchema.methods.getResetPasswordToken = function () {
  // Generating Token
  const resetToken = crypto.randomBytes(20).toString("hex");

  // Hashing and adding resetPasswordToken to userSchema
  this.resetPasswordToken = crypto
    .createHash("sha256")
    .update(resetToken)
    .digest("hex");

  this.resetPasswordExpire = Date.now() + 15 * 60 * 1000;

  return resetToken;
};

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

as suggest I have used already select false and also I select reset password token I am getting error when I try to return anything except user

Comment: That is what `.fields()` method is for in mongoose. I'm just guessing you are using mongoose since you haven't shown any code.

Comment: yes i am using mongoose i have mention that I am using mern stack

Comment: I think when after verifying the `user` in the backend, you are returning back the whole `user` like `return user`. Instead of doing that return only what you want like `return {_id, name}`

Comment: It's actualy `.select()` see the docs https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query-select i got it mixed up with other library.

Comment: @Molda  i have updated the question with my user model I tried  dharmic your suggestion but it gives error I cant return anything except user

Comment: Please show how you used the `.select()` method and what the error is.